# Angular vesion 7 core module missing during work

Tags: rxjs, angular7, angular-module

I was working on my angular 7 application and during the work automatically the red alert shown with the message that modules not found in my `app.modules.ts`. This is happening to me 3rd time.

Before that, I remove the `node_modules` dir and re-install the dependencies using `npm install`.

Here is the image for more understanding. Can anybody tell me about this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.